# Compile c code using gcc without installing mingW/cygwin

Tags: c, batch-file, gcc, compiler-errors

I have visual studio installed in my system. So its corresponding compiler and environment variables are set. When i try to compile c file using ***cl*** command, it works fine. Now i zipped mingW from another system and extracted it to my system. Say i have it in *D:/mingW*. Now i have created a batch file for compiling the c file. The contents of the batch file are,

```
set gccPath=D:/mingW/bin
%gccPath%/gcc.exe -c -std=c99 -o myC.o ../myC.c -I..\.
```

When i run this batch file, it is producing few errors. 
One such error is

```
stdio.h:209:71: error: macro "snprintf" requires 5 arguments, but only 4 given
```

The above error might be due to the fact that compiler takes the stdio.h of visual studio instead of mingW's default header file. 
Another error is,

```
error: previous declaration of 'xxxxFun' was here
```

What should i change in the batch script to compile the c file completely using mingW. 
Compilation process is successful when we use Visual Studio, but throws error if we use gcc for the same set of files

**EDIT:**
I fixed the latter error. 
Also the first error doesn't occur when stdio.h is included at first. But if we include stdio.h at the middle of the include section, the error comes.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <minmax.h>

#include "myFunctions.h"
#include "MyModule.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

When we have ***stdio.h*** at last as shown, the error is coming. If we move the line `#include <stdio.h>` to any other lines above `#include <MyModule.h>` , the specified error is not coming. Any reason behind this strange behavior?

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to *install* it? If it's just missing administrative privileges, you can "install" e.g. [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/) in any directory you have write access to and it comes with a shell where everything is nicely set up to just go and compile (and install "packages" with `pacman`).

Comment: @FelixPalmen Consider my code will do like, it will get the paths to different compilers(win64gcc, win32gcc => can be minGW or Cygwin) from user and it will compile the given c code using the specified compiler.

Comment: That's a very unusual thing to do. Instead, provide means to build with whatever toolchain you support (e.g. a batch file or msbuild script for `msvc`, a Makefile for `gcc`/ `clang`, etc).

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you @FelixPalmen

Comment: FWIW, I've finally ditched CygWin/MinGW now that Windows itself provides an Ubuntu subsystem.

Comment: The problem should be with "MyModule.h" . Investigate that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you are defining *snprintf* using macros in any of your header files. This error may be caused due to incorrect/unnecessary macro.